# How to store get a correct Glib::RefPtr to a non-widget using Gtk::Builder

Tags: c++, gtkmm

It is rather simple to get a `Glib::RefPtr` to any widget by using `get_widget` function of `Gtk::Builder`, but when it comes to getting other objects the corresponding `get_object` function returns `Glib::Object`, which is **not** easily convertable to the needed class (such as `Gtk::TreeView`).

What is the appropriate way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use `Glib::RefPtr<TheDerivedype>::cast_dynamic(object)` .

However, Gtk::TreeView (which you mention in your question) is a Gtk::Widget, so you would use get_widget() instead of get_object().

If you meant, Gtk::TreeModel, well,  defining GtkTreeModels in Glade, for use in gtkmm C++ code, is something that might work since we added some fixes for that in gtkmm recently:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742637

But it's not something that we generally expect to work - many C++ developers would prefer the static type safety of defining the DataModel structure completely in code, and not relying on a translation between C and C++ types. For instance: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-model.html.en#treeview-model-liststore

Answer (score 0):

Glib::RefPtr has a static template function which allows one to do what is needed. This function is logically called [`cast_static`](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1RefPtr.html#a2930d8c0eaa2610ee58cd267d325cc6e).

The sample code can be:

```
treeStore = 
  Glib::RefPtr< Gtk::TreeStore >::cast_static( builder->get_object("treestore1") );
```

Comment: There's also cast_dynamic(), which is a little safer. However, note that defining GtkTreeModels in Glade, for use in C++ code, is something that might work, but isn't generally expected to.

Comment: @murrayc Please consider making this into a full answer. I really would like to accept an answer that is not mine.